# VirtualBox: Run from external drive

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to get Virtual Box to run Windows and a program that ask for specific folders in the same External Hard Drive which is running Virtual Box. I initially set the folders using VirtualBox's share folder option and entering the \vboxsvr\ path. I wonder if I try to run the Virtual Box image on another host PC, would the Host's drive letter change and mess up my share folder?

I don't want to include the file folders within the image, because it's more handy outside.

Comment: Please mention the host and guest OS and which one you want to change. You may make a snapshot before and after sharing folder.

Answer (score 1):

As the other system has control over the external hard drive's letter, yes, it could change.
Before starting the virtual box, you will either need to change the hard drive letter in the OS, or change the settings in the virtual box to map to the different hard drive letter.

I have been using a set up like this for a while. If you use a specific letter higher in the alphabet (not the pre-assigned next one, like D: or E:), it should be stable and interchangeable.